# Facebook FB.init "Access is Denied" in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cors, facebook-javascript-sdk

In Internet Explorer 11 When I call FB.init as follows I get no fewer than eleven `SCRIPT5: Access is denied` errors:

```
FB.init({
    appId: appId,
    xfbml: true,
    version: "v2.5",
    channelUrl: channelUrl
});
```

In my case `channelUrl` is set to `http[s]://mysite/channel.html` which returns the following HTML document

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to make these errors disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `channelUrl` parameter, it should not be needed and it is not even listed in the docs anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.6

Also, check your code for including the JS SDK, make sure to not include the protocol (http/https).

If that does not solve the problem, please add a test link.